# Does the Trump campaign have standing to sue over defamation against Trump?

Tags: united-states, civil-law, defamation, standing

The NY Times, the Washington Post and, most recently, CNN, are being sued for defaming Trump.  [However](https://www.techdirt.com/articles/20200306/17044744052/trump-campaign-suing-all-his-media-enemies-files-another-silly-slapp-suit-over-cnn-opinion-piece.shtml):

> As with the other two cases, this one is being brought on behalf of the campaign, rather than Donald Trump himself as a party.

How can the Trump campaign have standing to sue for Trump?  I wouldn't think that they'd have the standing to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No

But they aren’t suing over defamation against Trump; the are suing over (alleged) defamation of the campaign:

> the Campaign "assessed the potential risks and benefits of again seeking Russia's help in 2020 and has decided to leave that option on the table."

Comment: And how is that actionable, since there’s no such thing as group libel?

Comment: No doubt there is a corporate legal person that can be identified by “the campaign” - that legal entity can be defamed. Also, the officers of the campaign as the decision makers could have been defamed.

Comment: @jeffronicus As Citizens United affirmed (not originated, as many people claim), entities other than natural persons can assert rights.